# How to create a clickable anchor tag in VueJS with filtered/ transformed data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS app that has the following style of (externally provided) data:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    posts: ['1:foo bar oof rab', '2:bar oof rab foo', '3:oof rab foo bar']
  }
}
```

I want my template to loop through posts and make everything to the left of the semi-colon a clickable anchor tag:

```
<li><a id="1" href="#1">1</a>:foo bar oof rab</li>
<li><a id="2" href="#2">2</a>:bar oof rab foo</li>
<li><a id="3" href="#3">3</a>:oof rab foo bar</li>
```

Using a filter it's easy to split the text from the anchor position:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-for="post in posts">
      <li>{{ post | trimAnchor }}:{{ post | trimPost }}</li>
    </v-for>
  </div>
</template>

filters: {
  trimPost: function(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    return value.split(':')[1]
  },
  trimAnchor: function(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    return value.split(':')[0]
  },
  hashAnchor: function(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    return '#'+value.split(':')[0]
  }
```

But filters don't work in v-bind or router-link:

```
<li>
  <div :id="{{ post | hashAnchor }}">
    <router-link="{{ post | hashAnchor }}">
      {{ post | trimAnchor }}
    </router-link>
  </div>
  :{{ post | trimPost }}
</li>
```

What is the correct approach to getting the output I'm after? Should I be using `computed` & if so, how?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these kind of cases I always recommend using a computed property. It keeps your template clean, and allows much freedom in preparing your data. Due to it being a computed property, it will automatically recalculate if your data were to change.

The first part is to create some object with all the necessary parts you require:

```
computed: {
  anchors () {
    if (!this.posts) {
      return [];
    }

    return this.posts.map(
      identifier => {
        const [anchor, text] = identifier.split(':', 2);

        return {
          anchor,
          text
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Then you destructure it where you need it. I also added a key to your v-for, assuming that the first part is guaranteed to be unique. It would need to be if your anchors are going to work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-for="{ anchor, text } in anchors" :key="anchor">
      <li><a :href="`#${anchor}`">{{ anchor }}</a>:{{ text }}</li>
    </v-for>
  </div>
</template>
```

Of course you can use filters if needed on the link or li body if you need.